# What do classes tf.train.Coordinator and class tf.train.QueueRunner do in tensorflow?

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I understand that both classes deal with threads. According to the documentation, tf.train.Coordinator coordinates the termination of a set of threads and tf.train.QueueRunner holds a list of enqueue operations for a queue, each to be run in a thread.

However, what is their role in simple words? When are they necessary during the training?

Answer (score 7):

QueueRunner:
When TensorFlow is reading the input, it needs to maintain multiple queues for it.  The queue serves all the workers that are responsible for executing the training step.  We use a queue because we want to have the inputs ready for the workers to operate on.  If you don't have a queue, you will be blocked on I/O and performance will degrade.

Coordindator:
This is part of tf.train.Supervisor. It's necessary because you need a controller to maintain the set of threads (know when main thread should terminate, request stopping of sub-threads, etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: WHY did they do this? All this functionality exisits in valina Python!